# selecton border is appear in on click

Tags: jquery, css

i am trying to set `scroll to top` `button` on my web-page, its is  working is well but when i click on button a selection border is appear that display in this image

[image]

and live demo is http://gazpo.com/downloads/tutorials/jquery/scrolltop/

i just try to remove that border to set `border:none` but is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That 'border' is the `outline`. It's used to denote the element which currently has focus. You can use CSS to disable it:

```
.scrollup {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've been wondering this myself sometimes but never took any effort to check what's it about :P Voted up because you gave some explanation, not just the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using outline property

```
outline: none;
```